# Is it possible to run different pipelines for same project in Jenkins?

Tags: android, android-studio, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

My team have a problem that we have an Android Studio project and inside it there is the main module and other feature modules (we want to create a multi-module arch).
But the problem is that our pipeline run all the tests from all the modules. So if a test break that is not responsibility from a specific team, it would impact them either way.
How can i fix this problem so that only the tests from a specific module/feature run and no all of them? We have a lot of different modules/features.

Comment: Ideally you _would_ run all the tests, since something breaking in one module silently could cause another module to fail on an integration test. I think you really have a VCS problem more than a CI one: you should aim to have a "master" branch where your tests are passing/clean, and then only merge in things that have confirmed to pass the other tests

Comment: @Rogue The problem is intermittents tests

Comment: We do have a master branch and we only merge the task branch there if the tests pass successfully. The problem is that sometimes the test pass one time and other times it doesn't and this impacts literally everyone.

Comment: A test failure in that case basically means one of two things: the code they added is broken, or the test itself is broken. Maven has several ways of specifying what tests/modules to run (and many side-effects that would cause a module to test anyhow, e.g. dependencies), but overall it still sounds like the problem is the tests being broken, not that you're running them. You said yourself intermittent tests are the problem, why make more of them?

Comment: Because we have a rule here that we need to do unit tests for every bug/feature. It usually should cover 80%. Sometimes i can change the code and make the test intermittent also.